# Lua xor function code

Tags: function, lua, xor

Does this code work as a xor function in Lua?

```
function xor (a,b)
if a ~= b then return true else return false end
end

i = false
j = false
if xor(not i, not j) then 
  print("one exclusive") 
else 
  print("both or none") 
end
```

Comment: i dunno does it?

Comment: `function xor(a,b) return not a ~= not b end`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your code works.

If `a` and `b` contain boolean values, then `a XOR b` is the same as `not(a == b)`, which of course is the same as
 `a ~= b`.